# first pin of package LQFP

Tags: pinout, footprint

this could be most stupid question but i couldnt find where is the first pin:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-11157-32-bit-Cortex-M4-Microcontroller-SAM4E16-SAM4E8_Datasheet.pdf

[image]

there is circle which identify pin 1, but is the pin on left or bottom side ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pin 1 is the left most pin of the bottom in your image.  Similar to the image below.

[image]

Comment: so i always have to put the index cornet at "top left" and the pin 1 would be in the left anti-clock wise?

Comment: You can orient the chip as you see fit.  In relation to the index dot or circle, pin 1 will always be anti-clockwise.

Comment: Do note that you cannot rely on the writing orientation - only the index mark.  In this case the writing happens to coincide with how the chip is often oriented in a pin numbering diagram, but it others the writing will be rotated.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I once had a pc board with a dozen SMD instrumentation amps. The label and a beveled edge were BOTH opposite the orientation shown by the index mark. Fortunately, there were enough chips to share the reversed power supply polarity, and none of the ICs were damaged. They still had to be reinstalled, of course, but I could test the board function while replacements were being ordered.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it is customary to count pins counter clock-wise from the indicator pin. From that image, I would suggest that Pin 1 is the far left pin on the bottom.